# Best way to add Vcard to node

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have a content type with CCK fields that make up contact information.  I was asked to add a VCard / Add to outlook feature.

I have a few ideas on how to do this but not sure which one is good.  My only actionable idea at the moment is to edit a template file for where it is displayed and create the vCard link within there.  However, I also use these in views and I'm not sure if that would translate to the view (I think not)

Is there such a thing as a field that is totally generated? For instance, I could add a vcard field that would then take you to the generated vCard?

I know that there is a module for this but it seems to only work with user profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me for a little self-promotion here, but I had the exact same issue a long time ago. This was the reason to build the [Views vCards](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_vcards) module.

> This module aims to provide a vCard attachment for views in a similar
>   way as the views built in feeds system does.
>
> The existing vCards modules [vCard](https://www.drupal.org/project/vcard) and [vCard Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/vcardfield) work with either
>   Profile2 data, or data the user has to enter himself. There was
>   however no solution for websites that use the Core profile system.
>   This module attempts to fill that gap. (But should in theory be able
>   to use all content that views has access to.)

So this module works with data from nodes and other entities as well.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, there is a [vcard module for user profiles](http://drupal.org/project/vcard), but there is also a [vcard module for cck fields](http://drupal.org/project/cck_vcard); you might want to try the module on a local test site, and check if there isn't any issue, as the usage statistics of this module is very low.